# Unable to Update DataTable, No Primary Key

Tags: c#, datatable, primary-key, datarow

I am updating a DataTable, and when I do it says `Table doesn't have a primary key.`  I changed how I created the table, and added a PrimaryKey, so what's going on?

I create the table, add columns, and add rows with data, and some blank values.
The DEBUG code right after it's populated works fine.

I then want to populate some of those blank values, but when I do I get the error.

Here is my code:

```
DataRow workrow;
DataTable ReasonCodeTable = new();

DataColumn dc1 = new();
dc1.ColumnName = "Reason Code";
dc1.DataType = typeof(string);

DataColumn dc2 = new();
dc2.ColumnName = "LocationID";
dc2.DataType = typeof(string);

DataColumn dc3 = new();
dc3.ColumnName = "Location";
dc3.DataType = typeof(string);

DataColumn dc4 = new();
dc4.ColumnName = "Issue";
dc4.DataType = typeof(string);

DataColumn dc5 = new();
dc5.ColumnName = "Description";
dc5.DataType = typeof(string);

DataColumn dc6 = new();
dc6.ColumnName = "Who Edited";
dc6.DataType = typeof(string);

DataColumn dc7 = new();
dc7.ColumnName = "Last Edit (UTC)";
dc7.DataType = typeof(string);


ReasonCodeTable.Columns.Add(dc1);
ReasonCodeTable.Columns.Add(dc2);
ReasonCodeTable.Columns.Add(dc3);
ReasonCodeTable.Columns.Add(dc4);
ReasonCodeTable.Columns.Add(dc5);
ReasonCodeTable.Columns.Add(dc6);
ReasonCodeTable.Columns.Add(dc7);
ReasonCodeTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dc1, dc2 };

// Builds ReasonCodeTable
foreach (string code in codeList)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> loc in Locations)
    {
        workrow = ReasonCodeTable.NewRow();
        workrow["Reason Code"] = code;
        workrow["LocationID"] = loc.Key;
        workrow["Location"] = loc.Value;
        workrow["Issue"] = "";
        workrow["Description"] = "";
        workrow["Who Edited"] = "";
        workrow["Last Edit (UTC)"] = "";
        ReasonCodeTable.Rows.Add(workrow);
    }
}


/*** DEBUG BEGIN ***/
foreach(DataRow dr in ReasonCodeTable.Rows)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < ReasonCodeTable.Columns.Count; cnt++)
        Console.WriteLine($"{ReasonCodeTable.Columns[cnt].ColumnName}: {dr[cnt]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"");
}
/*** DEBUG END ***/


foreach (DataRow _rcdr in ReasonCodeTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow _dr in p21CodeTable.Rows)
    {
        if ( (p21CodeTable.Rows.Find(_rcdr["Reason Code"]) != null) && (p21CodeTable.Rows.Find("P21") != null) )
        {
            _rcdr["Desciption"] = _dr["description"];
            _rcdr["Who Edited"] = _dr["editwho"];
            _rcdr["Last Edit (UTC)"] = _dr["editdate"];
        }
    }
}

/*** DEBUG BEGIN ***/
foreach(DataRow dr in ReasonCodeTable.Rows)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < ReasonCodeTable.Columns.Count; cnt++)
        Console.WriteLine($"{ReasonCodeTable.Columns[cnt].ColumnName}: {dr[cnt]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"");
}
/*** DEBUG END ***/
```

R64CodeTable:

```
company: IBM
code: 10
description: Inventory Count
editdate: 2020-05-19
editwho: User12

company: IBM
code: 11
description: Data Error
editdate: 2021-06-28
editwho: User12

company: IBM
code: 12
description: Warehouse Error
editdate: 2021-08-19
editwho: User06
```

ReasonCodeTable after initial population:

```
Reason Code: 10
LocationID: R64
Location: R64
Issue:
Description:
Who Edited:
Last Edit (UTC):

Reason Code: 10
LocationID: WH1
Location: Chicago
Issue:
Description:
Who Edited:
Last Edit (UTC):

Reason Code: 11
LocationID: R64
Location: R64
Issue:
Description:
Who Edited:
Last Edit (UTC):
```

ReasonCodeTable how it should look after update:

```
Reason Code: 10
LocationID: R64
Location: R64
Issue:
Description: Inventory Count
Who Edited: User12
Last Edit (UTC): 2020-05-19

Reason Code: 10
LocationID: WH1
Location: Chicago
Issue:
Description:
Who Edited:
Last Edit (UTC):

Reason Code: 11
LocationID: R64
Location: R64
Issue:
Description: Data Error
Who Edited: User12
Last Edit (UTC): 2021-06-28
```

I don't understand what's going on with the primary key.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/navigating-datarelations , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarelation?view=net-6.0 , and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.add?view=net-6.0#system-data-datacolumncollection-add(system-string-system-type)

Comment: @user9938   Ok, but why did the first debug code work, and then the next foreach bcause an error.  Looks like I can do `ReasonCodeTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { "Reason Code","LocationID" };`

Comment: Please add some sample data to your post. Also the following statement doesn't make sense: _What I'm trying to do is to update the ReasonCodeTablefrom the R64CodeTable by matching the "code" to the "Reason Code" and if it has R64 in it_ The rest of the paragraph could use a re-write, as well, to make things more clear.

Comment: A `DataTable` is usually used when a database is the source for the data (although this isn't a requirement). It seems that you aren't using any syntax that would benefit from a `DataTable` - you could very well have used a `List` of a class. (ex: `List<MyClass1>`).

Comment: @user9938 Updated the question.  I changed how I built the DataTable so I could create a PrimaryKey.  I don't know why it still says it isn't there.

Comment: If all columns are going to be `String`, specifying the data type is unnecessary. It seems that one of the columns could be created as `int`, and another could be created as `DateTime`-but one needs to refer to the data source to find that information. From looking at one of your previous posts, it seems that your data source may be JSON.

Comment: @user9938  The data source is SQL and a json file.  I read them into the Locations Dictionary and R64CodeTable DataTable.  I don't want a DataSet, I want a DataTable (not a DataSet with a single table either). I don't understand why I have to have relationships just to set the value in a DataTable.  That seems seriously convoluted.  It also doesn't explain why I am still getting the Primary Key error when I have clearly set one.

Comment: I'm having difficulty following what you're attempting to do.. Also, the code you posted is missing information on `codeList`, `Locations`, and `p21CodeTable`.  For the part that's not working, you may want to try using `for` instead of `foreach` to see if it resolves your issue.